# Converting database query in "Entity Relational Language" to SQL statement

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

Title says it all.  I am given a table instructor:

```
mysql> describe instructor;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID        | char(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dept_name | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary    | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have to write a SQL statement for this database query:

Ơ dept_name="Physics"(instructor)

Comment: You have described your task.  So where are you stuck?  What have you already tried?

Comment: I have to convert the linked image to a SQL statement. Not create the table

Comment: So you're supposed to `SELECT` the the whole galaxy (made up of all the stars, like `*`) `FROM` your `instructor` `WHERE` the `dept_name` equals (`=`) `'Physics'`? Did I understand that right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE instructor;
```

will give you create table query.

More insight about it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: The table is already there. I do not have to create another one.